# Redux push to 2nd level object with array

Tags: redux, immutable.js

So i have a redux store that looks like this:

```
posts : {
   posts: [
      0: { },
      1: { }
   ]
}
```

I want to concat the array with extra items like this:

```
case LOAD_MORE_POSTS_SUCCESS:
  return {
    ...state,
    posts: [...state.posts, action.posts],
    isFetching: false,
  }
```

However this is pushing the extra posts only into the first level, ive tried doing something like this (no luck):

```
case LOAD_MORE_POSTS_SUCCESS:
  return {
    ...state,
    posts: [...state.posts.posts, action.posts],
    isFetching: false,
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried something like:

```
case LOAD_MORE_POSTS_SUCCESS:
  return {
    ...state,
    posts: {
      posts: [...state.posts.posts, action.posts]
    },
    isFetching: false,
  }
```

And if `action.posts` is an array (the plural form hints that it is), consider using:

```
posts: {
  posts: [...state.posts.posts, ...action.posts]
}
```

Comment: Perfect thanks for that - I needed to include the spread operator for the action: ...action.posts.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Gila Artzi - My final code looked like this:

```
case LOAD_MORE_POSTS_SUCCESS:
  return {
    ...state,
    posts: [...state.posts, ...action.posts],
    isFetching: false,
  }
```